# Is it a bad practice to output error messages in a function with one input and one output

Tags: c, data-structures, coding-style

I was once told that functions with one input and one output(not exactly one) should not print messages when being called. But I don't understand. Is it for security or just for convention?

Let me give an example. How to deal with an attempt that access data in a sequential list with an  incorrect index?

```
// 1. Give out the error message inside the function directly.
DataType GetData(seqList *L, int index)
{
    if (index < 0  ||  index >= L->length) {
        printf("Error: Access beyond bounds of list.\n");
        // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return L->data[index];
}

// 2. Return a value or use a global variable(like errno) that
//    indicates whether the function performs successfully.
StateType GetData(seqList *L, int index, int *data)
{
    if (index < 0  ||  index >= L->length) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    *data = L->data[index];
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Imho this convention is stupid, the number of arguments has literally nothing to do with the internal complexity or need of printing text to a console.

Comment: The only real rule is that the function should conform to the error-reporting conventions of the overall application.  If those conventions say printf the Gettysburg Address and then return the square root of pi, that's what you do.

Comment: @drahnr My bad. What I really mean is that the function is not a procedure.

Comment: Now you're going to get us started on "function" vs "procedure" vs "subroutine" vs ...

Comment: @drahnr: I think the real issue is that a function which only has a single return value (i.e. no secondary channel to return results via a passed-in pointer) may not have a reasonable way to report errors. If so, it's a flaw in the interface design. *Usually*, you can find a sentinel value (e.g. negative values for signed return types, `(size_t)-1` for `size_t`, null for pointers, etc.) though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two things going on here:

1. Any visible and unexpected side-effect such as writing to streams is generally bad, and not just for functions with one input and one output. If I was using a list library, and it started silently writing error messages to the same output stream I was using for my regular output, I'd consider that a problem. However, if *you* are writing such a function for your own personal use, and you know ahead of time that the action you want taken is always to print a message and `exit()`, then it's fine. Just don't force this behavior on everyone else.
2. This is a specific case of the general problem of how to inform callers about errors. A lot of the time, a function cannot know the correct response to an error, because it doesn't have the context that the caller does. Take `malloc()`, for instance. The vast majority of the time, when `malloc()` fails, I just want to terminate, but once in a great while I might want to deliberately fill the memory by calling `malloc()` until it fails, and then proceed to do something else. In this case, I don't want the function to decide whether or not to terminate - I just want it to tell me it's failed, and then pass control back to me.

There are a number of different approaches to handling errors in library functions:

1. Terminate - fine if you're writing a program yourself, but bad for a general purpose library function. In general, for a library function, you'll want to let the caller decide what to do in the case of an error, so the function's role is limited to informing the caller of the error.
2. Return an error value - sometimes OK, but sometimes there is no feasible error value. `atoi()` is a good case in point - all the possible values it returns could be correct translations of the input string. It doesn't matter what you return on error, be it `0`, `-1` or anything else, there is no way to distinguish an error from a valid result, which is precisely why you get undefined behavior if it encounters one. It's also semantically questionable from a slightly purist point of view - for instance, a function which returns the square root of a number is one thing, but a function which *sometimes* returns the square root of a number, but which *sometimes* returns an error code rather than a square root is another thing. You can lose the self-documenting simplicity of a function when return values serve two completely separate purposes.
3. Leave the program in an error state, such as setting `errno`. You still have the fundamental problem that if there is no feasible return value, the function still can't *tell* you that an error has occurred. You could set `errno` to 0 in advance and check it afterwards every time, but this is a lot of work, and may just not be feasible when you start involving concurrency.
4. Call an error handling function - this basically just passes the buck, since the error function then also has to address the issues above, but at least you could provide your own. Also, as R. notes in the comments below, other than in very simple cases like "always terminate on any error" it can be asking too much of a single global error handling function to be able to sensibly handle any error that might arise in a way that your program can them resume normal execution. Having numerous error handling functions and passing the appropriate ones individually to each library function is technically possible, but hardly an optimal solution. Using error handling functions in this way can also be difficult or even impossible to use correctly in the presence of concurrency.
5. Pass in an argument that gets modified by the function if it encounters an error. Technically feasible, but it's not really desirable to add an additional parameter for this purpose to every library function ever written.
6. Throw an exception - your language has to support them to do this, and they come along with all kinds of associated difficulties including unclear structure and program flow, more complex code, and the like. Some people - I'm not one of them - consider exceptions to be the moral equivalent of `longjmp()`.

All the possible ways have their drawbacks and advantages, as of yet humanity has not discovered the perfect way of reporting errors from library functions.

Comment: You can always apply solution #2 if you want to: Just create a custom struct that contains a validity flag first, then the return data. Anyway, you have my +1 for providing the most well-rounded answer.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Yeah, I just added a new #5 to cover this type of thing before I saw your comment. It works, but I think it's not usually desirable.

Comment: It's interesting here to observe how often, in questions involving Objective-C, an `error` parm is coded but the error code is never checked on the calling side, even when that would lead directly to the solution of the OP's problem.

Comment: Comment on point 4: often libraries which take this approach have a serious problem in that the error-handling function provided "by the caller" is global, meaning that the library is difficult to use if there's more than one caller, and impossible to use correctly in multi-threaded programs. The only valid way to use a caller-provided error handling callback is if it's passed to the function each time or stored in a context specific to the caller. Both libavcodec and glib are popular libraries that suffer from an issue of this form.

Comment: @R.. Good point, I added a bit more to point 4.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should make sure you have a consistent and coherent error handling strategy, which means considering whether you want to pass an error up to a higher level or handle it at the level it initially occurs. This decision has nothing to do with how many inputs and outputs a function has.

In a deeply embedded system where a memory allocation failure occurs at a critical juncture, for example, there's no point passing that error back up (and indeed you may well not be able to) - all you can do might be enter a tight loop to let the watchdog reset you. In this case there's no point reserving invalid return values to indicate error, or indeed in even checking the return value at all if it doesn't make sense to do so. (Note I am not advocating just lazily not bothering to check return values, that is a different matter entirely).

On the other hand, in a lovely beautiful GUI app you probably want to fail as gracefully as possible and pass the error up to a level where it can be either worked around / retried / whatever is appropriate; or presented to the user as an error if nothing else can be done.

Comment: Of course, everyone knows what you SHOULD do is throw an exception.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm guessing you just meant for that comment to be humorously inflammatory, but this question is tagged C and there is no such thing as an exception in C. Even in languages with exceptions, unless all the code involved is using them correctly, they can do more harm than good...

Comment: Everyone knows you should `longjmp`.

Comment: @R.. - My somewhat tangential point was that exceptions solve most of the problems discussed here.

Comment: @HotLicks: And my point was that (aside from not existing in C) they create a whole bunch of new problems. Whether these new problems are worse than the old ones is a question without a clear answer.

Comment: @R.. - But fodder for lots of good arguments.  Somewhere there's a middle ground, and I've seen hints of it here and here, but have never tried to flesh it out.

Comment: Basically I've never seen a way to use exceptions correctly in non-functional languages without putting try/catch blocks at the exact same places you'd put the equivalent if/else blocks for checking return values. If you just let exceptions propagate back without catching them, you almost always end up leaving inconsistent intermediate state. The only way to avoid this is with purely functional languages where the partially-completed computation/state is automatically discarded as a consequence of the language.

Comment: Not to start the whole exception debate here (;)), but the point is that you can use exceptions for reasonably rare conditions and only those prepared to deal with rare conditions need listen for them.  You definitely do not need catch blocks everywhere you'd have checked return codes, since most errors will default to "abort".  And exceptions (properly used) are far better than most other schemes in terms of helping to maintain consistent state.  People have been killed by return-code-based schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a bad practice; even worse is that you're sending the output to `stdout` rather than `stderr`. This could end up corrupting data by mixing error message in with output.

Personally, I believe very strongly that this kind of "error handling" is harmful. There is no way you can validate that the caller passed a valid value for `L`, so checking the validity of `index` is inconsistent. The documented interface contract for the function should simply be that `L` must be a valid pointer to an object of the correct type, and `index` a valid index (in whatever sense is meaningful to your code). If an invalid value for `L` or `index` is passed, this is a *bug in your code*, not a legitimate error that can occur at runtime. If you need help debugging it, the `assert` macro from `assert.h` is probably a good idea; it makes it easy to turn off the check when you no longer need it.

One possible exception to the above principle would be the case where the value of `L` is coming from other data structures in your program, but `index` is coming from some external input that's not under your control. You could then perform an external validation step before calling this function, but if you always need the validation, it makes sense to integrate it like you're doing. However, in that case you need to have a way to report the failure to the caller, rather than printing a useless and harmful message to `stdout`. So you need to either reserve one possible return value as an error sentinel, or have an extra argument that allows you to return both a result and an error status to the caller.

Comment: Thank you. I often run into such trouble that whether to check all the arguments for stability. Now I see.

Answer (score 1):

Return a reserved value that's invalid for a success condition. For example, `NULL`.

It is advisable not to print because:

1. It doesn't help the calling code reason about the error.
2. You're writing to a stream that might be used by higher level code for something else.
3. The error may be recoverable higher, so you might be just printing misleading error messages.

---

As others have said, *consistency* in how you deal with error conditions is also an important factor. But consider this:

- If your code is used as a component of another application, one that does not follow your printing convention, then by printing you're not allowing the client code to remain faithful to its own strategy. Thus, using this strategy you impose your convention to all related code.
- On the other hand, if you follow the "cleaner" solution of returning a reserved value and the client code wants to follow the printing convention, the client code can easily adapt to what you return and even print an error, by making simple wrappers around your functions. Thus, using this strategy you give the users of your code enough space to choose the strategy that best works for them and to be faithful to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `perror()` to display error messages rather than using printf()

Syntax:

```
void perror(const char *s);
```

Also error messages are supposed to be sent to the stderr stream than stdout.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best if code deals with one thing only.  It is easier to understand, it is easier to use, and is applicable in more instances.

Your GetData function that prints an error message isn't suitable for use in cases where there may not be a value. i.e. The calling code wants to try to get a value and handle the error by using a default if it doesn't exist.

Since GetData doesn't know the context it can't report a good error message. As an example higher up the call stack we can report hey you forgot to give this user an age, vs in GetData where all it knows is we couldn't get some value.

What about a multithreaded situation?  GetData seems like it would be something that might get called from multiple threads.  With a random bit of IO shoved in the middle it will cause contention over who has access to the console if all the threads need to write at the same time.

Comment: "code deals with one thing only", that is what I want to say.